# saving many to many form field values in to database table(model)

Tags: django, forms, many-to-many, models

I had a model which i converted it to form as below

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()

class College(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
    place = models.CharField()
```

**form.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import College

class CollegeForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = College
```

**views.py**

```
def college_view(request):
    form = CollegeForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CollegeForm(request.POST):
        if form.is_valid():
            college_obj = College.objects.create(name=request.POST['name'],
                                                place=request.POST['place'],
                                                books= ???????)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    return render_to_response('college-detail.html', {'form':form})
```

So what all i am doing above is

1. Created a model called `College` that has a `many to many` link to `Book`
2. Converted the model in to form using `ModelForm` and rendered as html
3. When the form gets submitted with values, in view i am getting that values from
   request.POST and trying to save in to the `College` model.

   but as you can observe the college form has one `many to many` field and two `CharField`,
   so i had saved the char fields directly in to the table, but i am stuck near saving the
   many to many field `books` in the table(that is model `College`)

so can anyone please let me know in brief on how to save `manytomany` fields in to the database tables i mean models that has `manytomany` fields

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Why are you creating the model directly if you're using a ModelForm? ModelForms have a .save() method, I'd assume they would do what you're expecting, but haven't tried it (I stay away from ModelForms in general, too much implicit behavior for my taste).

Comment: I am creating models because i need the entered information for some purposes and hence need to save them.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you read the documentation on [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), you will notice that they are equipped with a [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method, which already provides the functionality you want.

You can use

```
if form.is_valid():
     form.save()
```

or, if you want to add more values to the model, you can

```
if form.is_valid():
     instance = form.save(commit=False)
     instance.custom_field = custom_value
     instance.save()
```

Comment: yeah right, but here i want to save the data in to some other mdoel, but not form right? as you can see the question marks in above code, so what needs to be done in order to the save the many2many fields values like [1,2,3] in to books ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. As per documentation, save() method saves or creates (commit=False) a new model associated with the form. It does not save the Form itself.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `form.is_valid()`, calling `form.save()` will do job of saving many to many data for you as well. If in case you want to change/add data to form objects before saving you can do

```html
f = form.save(commit=False)
```

After calling save with `commit=False` django makes available a `save_m2m()` method on your form object. Notice *form* not *f*. After you're done manipulating the *f* object, you can go ahead and call `save_m2m()` to save many to many data of that form.

```html
form.save_m2m()
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method